# ZfcUser and Bjyauthorize: setup routing to different actions for different roles after authentication

Tags: zend-framework2, zfcuser, zend-acl, bjyauthorize

I am new to Zend Framework 2. I am using [`ZfcUser`](https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcUser) and [`Bjyauthorize`](https://github.com/bjyoungblood/BjyAuthorize).

I have three different roles: `admin`, `instructor`, and `student`. Each of them is supposed to get different views and access to different actions after authentication.

I am familiar with **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16674060/zend-framework2-using-zfcuser-bjyauthorize-routing)** programmatic solution: when the program checks the role in and dispatches each role to a relative action. However, I feel there should be a solution during configuration stage for this. I found some **[attempts](http://javahow.net/questions/16053479/zfcuser-redirect-roles-to-different-pages-after-login)**, but I don't think it was ever merged to the main branch, and I do not want to modify `ZfcUser` on my own.

Any advice? Should I continue with programmatic solution?